# How to decode XML file without using XML Decoder?

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

I have a XML file which was encoded using java.beans.XMLEncoder. I cannot use java.beans.XMLDecoder to decode it, as the class of encoded object is not present in my project. Is there a way to obtain values in xml without using java.beans.XMLDecoder, xmlDecoder.readObject() method ?

Comment: can you use another xml decode  ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several [APIs for parsing XML in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm) which don't require you to deserialize an object.  Once you have a DOM, XPath is a useful way to query its contents.  You will need to know what you're looking for, though.

Comment: I tried, but the xml is difficult to parse. Everything starts from <void> tags and repeated elements are there( likethe one in this url -http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/files/how-do-i-read-a-javabean-from-an-xml-file-using-xmldecoder/mybean.xml). I'm trying to find an existing implementation.